# 90112 bytes limit for data files?

Tags: android

I create data file in android for my application in the app's data directory. The write is successful with no exceptions but file contents are not complete. It truncates at 90112 bytes. Any idea what is going on ? Is there a limit ?

Here is the snippet

```
try {
            fos = parentActivity.openFileOutput(mmCacheFName,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE | Context.MODE_APPEND);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
            BufferedWriter bosw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            int indx = lastIndx - 10;
            while (indx >= 0) {
                IEventHolder ev = deltaList.get(indx);
                bosw.write(ev.getRawData() + "\n");
                indx--;
            }
            osw.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace() 
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null)
                    fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hard to tell. How much free space do you have? Do you have example code?

Comment: It may have something to do with the Binder transactions that allow about 100KByte binary data being sent through them at once. Try writing this file in few steps, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. I figured out what the issue was, I should be flushing and closing the BufferedWriter instead of OutputStreamWriter. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

There might be lots of reasons. If you send your code, it's easier to track the problem. But you could check:

1. you have closed your Stream when writing to the file (It is recommended that you do it in a finally block) like this:

   try{
   ....
   write the data to the file with some outputStream
   }finally{
         outputStream.close();
   }
2. If you want to read the data before closing the stream, make sure your output-stream does not buffer the output. if it does, before reading the data, flush the output to the file:

   outputStream.flush();
3. Check for any exception that might be caught, but not logged, some code like this:

   try{
       ...
   }catch(IOException ex){
       // here must log the exception.
   }

}

Comment: I tried as you having the outputstream.close() in the finally block but it did not help. Let me modify my question to contain the snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I figured out what the issue was, I should be flushing and closing the BufferedWriter instead of OutputStreamWriter. Thanks again